# Is Bliss Font for commercial?

Tags: font-licensing

Is the Bliss font a free product or do I need to purchase a license for a company usage.

Comment: Doesn't a google search reveal anything? Have you tried searching for "type" instead of "font"?

Answer (score 2):

Bliss is **not** a free font, so it's a typeface that requires purchase. I'd highly recommend reading through the [licensing terms on the font designers website](https://typography.net/licensing#desktop) and make sure you'll be able to apply it in the ways your company is planning on using it.

**Bliss Regular** is also available for purchase on this site £80.00 (~$114) and the **Bliss Family Pack** (14 styles) is available for £560.00 (~$800).

Comment: @user113265 You probably can find members of Bliss font family downloadable for free . In our world there are plenty of areas where law and order aren't established and nobody cares if you download a copy and use it like it was your own. But in developed countries using that font without paying is a crime. In addition you take a risk to bring in a bunch of malware.